# Connecting to a device with a static IP on a different subnet

Tags: networking, subnet, static-ip

So, my laptop is at Location A receiving a DHCP address in the client's subnet on 10.60.50.x/24. There is a device at Location B with a static IP at 192.168.1.39 (trying to connect to its web interface to switch over to DHCP) but on a different client subnet of 10.60.51.x/26. Now, my laptop can connect to any device that has a 10.60.51.x address, but is there a way to connect to that static IP on that different subnet? I hope I'm explaining it clearly enough. I understand networking concepts to a degree but am still missing pieces here and there and this is one.

Comment: Without a common connection like a VPN both those addresses only exist within their individual networks

Answer (score 0):

> There is a device at Location B with a static IP at 192.168.1.39 (trying to connect to its web interface to switch over to DHCP) but on a different client subnet of 10.60.51.x/26. Now, my laptop can connect to any device that has a 10.60.51.x address, but is there a way to connect to that static IP on that different subnet?

In theory, yes, but the network administrators will need to be involved – your PC configuration will not help here. Specifically:

1. The router that handles at location B needs to have the 192.168.1.0/24 (approximately) subnet *added* to the same interface that currently handles the 10.60.51.x/26 subnet. If your device currently expects 192.168.1.1 as its gateway (for example), then the router at location B should have that address.
2. Option A: All the routers along the way A–B need to have routes for 192.168.1.0/24 defined (perhaps manually, perhaps automatically through OSPF).

   Option B: If the route would conflict, then the router at location B needs to have DNAT set up (which is basically "port forwarding") to translate one of its unused 10.60.51.x addresses to your device's 192.168.1.39 address.
3. In some cases (e.g. if the device refuses "out of subnet" connections, or if it doesn't have a gateway set), the router at location B also needs SNAT (masquerading) set up to hide your IP address.

---

Potential alternative method: If there is another device at location B (in the 10.60.51.x subnet), such as a PC or the same router, that you can SSH into and configure, then that device could possibly have the additional subnet added and be used as a proxy (SSH tunneling). It's a bit of a last-resort option, though.

---

(Pedantic note: If it's a /26, then there are actually *four* "10.60.51.x/26" subnets: one is .0/26 (.0–.63), then .64/26 (.64–.127), then .128/26 (etc.), then finally .192/26.)

Answer (score 0):

leave the laptop ip configuration blank, and set the DHCP server at location B should reserve and assign that static ip (192.168.1.39) to the laptop via the laptop MAC address.

(and if you need static on the other place, do the same on location A)